# Python saving multiframe TIFF as multiple JPEG

Tags: python, jpeg, tiff

I have a TIFF file with multiple frames. I found that if I open the TIFF file and call the `seek(1)` I can seek to the second frame. This is working, except when I go to save the image as a jpg, it only saves the first frame and not my current frame.

How can I save multiple frames to different JPG files?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.tiff')
im.save('test.jpeg')
```

I need to do something like...

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open('test.tiff')
im.seek(1)
im.save('test.jpeg')
```

and have it save the second frame and not the first.

Comment: Your code works for me... It saves the second frame. (Uses example from here. http://www.nightprogrammer.org/development/multipage-tiff-example-download-test-image-file/ with PIL 1.1.7 and Python 3.5 on Win7)

Comment: Does it save the second page as a separate image? When I execute it on my Ubuntu Linux it always saves the first frame

Comment: Yes, this is effectively "Multipage TIFF Example Page 2" which is saved to the file. Working also on my ArchLinux (same version of programs). You may be facing a bug in your version then. Maybe ask upstream?